# Xlwings : Thick Box Border in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xlwings

I am currently using xlwings, for purpose of creating borders but unable to create the Thick Box Border (i.e only external). Below its the code to create ALL borders

```
sheet_name.range("$A$1:$F$20").api.Borders.Weight = 1
```